# When can I omit the dot character that indicate the current directory

Tags: files, directory

Should I use dot to indicate the current directory for accessing directories or should I use it for files only?

For example, if the current directory is `foo` and it contains `bar` directory and `baz.txt` file, when can I omit the dot character?

```
./bar
./baz.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can omit the dot caracter for folders if you wish but the both are OK

```
cd ./bar
```

or

```
cd bar
```

are equivalent - but you'll agree that the second is more convenient.

If you want to execute your `bar.txt` file (which may be executable with `chmod 755` for example) then you have to use the ./ indicator

`./bar.txt` will execute the script

`bar.txt` will do nothing

`cat bar.txt` or `cat ./bar.txt` will do the same.

hope that help :)

EDIT: if you want to have more information about why ./ is needed to run script, just follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash

> Because on Unix, usually, the current directory is not in $PATH.
>   When you type a command the shell looks up a list of directories, as > specified by the PATH variable. The current directory is not in that list.

(@cnicutar)

Comment: Is it better now ? :)

Comment: `cd ./bar` isn't always equivalent to `cd bar`: the `./` bypasses `CDPATH`

Answer (score 3):

In places that expect a path to a file, `./foo` is equivalent to `foo`. There are only a few places where writing `./foo` is useful.

Writing `./foo` is useful when what is expected is not necessarily a path, but possibly a file name that may be looked up in a search path. The most common case is when invoking an executable command. Executable programs are searched in directories listed in the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), but this lookup is only performed if the given command name does not contain a slash. So `ls` invokes the `ls` command found in the PATH (typically `/bin/ls`), whereas `./ls` invokes the executable program `ls` in the current directory. More generally, writing `./foo` also bypasses any shell alias, function or builtin called `foo`.

Another use for the `./` prefix is to avoid trouble with file names starting with some special characters. In particular, when you pass a file name as an argument to a command, in most cases, the command allows options starting with `-`. If the file name comes from a variable, you may not be sure that the file name doesn't start with `-`. Writing `"./$filename"` instead of `"$filename"` ensures that it won't be misinterpreted as an option if it starts with `-`. However this only works if `$filename` is a relative path (i.e. not beginning with `/`). Another more general method of protecting file names is to put them after `--` on the command line: `mycommand -- "$filename"` (`--` conventionally indicates that what follows are non-option arguments only) (however this doesn't always work in one specific case: if `$filename` is `-`, many commands treat that as meaning “standard input”). On this topic, see also [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)